# Spring 3 MVC: form backing object has to be in session? How can I avoid this?

Tags: java, forms, spring, model-view-controller, object

I read a few tutorials about forms and submission in Spring 3 MVC. All these examples indicate that storing the backing object in the session the following way:

@SessionAttributes({"command"})

I used old versions of Spring in which there is a formBacking method if a controller inherits SimpleFormController.

protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)

If my understanding is right, the old version approach loads the form backing object on the fly when the form submits and there is no need of storing this object in session.

If my understanding about Spring 3 MVC is right, then I don't like the session approach because it consumes lot of memory in case of large users and the object stored in session might be outdated at the time of form submission.

Can I avoid storing the form backing object in session in Spring 3's MVC? Any pointer?

Thanks for any input and please correct me if I am wrong.

Regards.

---

Anyone else knows whether my understanding is right?

> > the GET controller adding the object to the model equates to adding it to session. How can Spring remember the object as the backing object when a form is submitted? Cheers.

How can the form backing object added to the model in the GET controller survive a round trip between the server and client when a form is submitted? Does Spring serialize it on disk? I am guessing...

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply do not list your command among the `@SessionAttributes`, it will be instantiated every time.

In the old Controller API, implementations could decide whether or not they want to keep their command objects on the session: see [`AbstractFormController.isSessionForm()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractFormController.html#isSessionForm%28%29). `SimpleFormController` returned `false`, while `AbstractWizardFormController` returned `true`, as it actually required the command to be stored on the session.

You can check how a model attribute is bound in the `HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveModelAttribute(...)` private method:

```
if (implicitModel.containsKey(name)) {
    // ...
} else if (this.methodResolver.isSessionAttribute(name, paramType)) {
    // ...
else {
    bindObject = BeanUtils.instantiateClass(paramType);
}
```

So obviously, the binder will use a fresh instance if you don't explicitely declare it as session attribute; exactly the same as returning false from `AbstractFormController.isSessionForm()`.

---

> How can the form backing object added to the model in the GET controller survive a round trip between the server and client when a form is submitted? Does Spring serialize it on disk? I am guessing...

Spring does not (always) need to store the backing object between form view and form submission. If everything that you need in order to populate your command object comes with the request, Spring can simply instantiate a new command object (either itself or let you do it if you provide a proper method) and then bind the request to that fresh instance.

See above the comparison with the old API regarding the difference between `SimpleFormController` and `AbstractWizardFormController` implementations. The first does not need to store anything on the session and it will bind the submit request to a newly created object. With the new annotated handlers, the flow is the same; if you don't want to store it, it will be recreated on submit: `BeanUtils.instantiateClass(...)` or your own custom factory method.

Comment: Costi, thanks so much for your detailed explanation. I feel I am getting there, but not completely without seeing an example.

>>Spring can simply instantiate a new command object (either itself or let you do it if you provide a proper method) and then bind the request to that fresh instance.

Could you please point me to an Spring 3 MVC example in which the form backing object is loaded from the database at the time of form submission (or maybe you can show me the steps and methods?).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the backing object to the model, not to the Session. Here's one tutorial... http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-form-example.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read that tutorial before my post. In this tutorial, the form backing object is not loaded from the database. I am talking about loading the form backing object from the database.

If my understanding is right, the GET controller adding the object to the model equates to adding it to session. How can Spring remember the object as the backing object when a form submitted? 

Cheers.

Comment: ironically @madth3 's answer is exactly what I was looking for i.e. a form backed by an Object not associated with the DB, and other searching may come across this too.